# Query / create subset of turtles for each turtle

Tags: simulation, netlogo, agent-based-modeling

I have an `agentset` where all the turtles have different values for age/experience. What I would like to do is find the more experienced turtles for each turtle and then follow those turtles. Unfortunately, I get the following error for the `ifelse [ age-experience > my-own-age-experience ]` line:

> Expected a TRUE/FALSE here, rather than a list or block.

Here's my code:

```
turtles-own [
  age-experience
  more-dominant
  dominant-flockmates  
]

to setup
  clear-all
  create-turtles 10 [ set age-experience random-float 1 ]
  reset-ticks
end

to go
  ask turtles [
    find-dominant-flockmates
    ifelse any? dominant-flockmates
      [ show "follow the more dominant flockmates" ]
      [ show "take the lead" ]
  ]
  tick
end

to find-dominant-flockmates
  let my-own-age-experience age-experience
  ask other turtles [
    ifelse [ age-experience > my-own-age-experience ]
      [ set more-dominant true ]
      [ set more-dominant false ]
  ]
  set dominant-flockmates other turtles with [ more-dominant ]
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, you have several choices here. You can get rid of the error by removing the `[]`

```
to find-dominant-flockmates
  let my-own-age-experience age-experience
  ask other turtles [
    ifelse age-experience > my-own-age-experience
      [ set more-dominant true ]
      [ set more-dominant false ]
  ]
  set dominant-flockmates other turtles with [ more-dominant ]
end
```

But there's much more efficient ways to code this. If you are going to use the variable `more-dominant` for other purposes (so you need it), you can use `ifelse-value` like this (and because it's true/false, you don't actually need ifelse-value but it's a good thing to know about):

```
to find-dominant-flockmates
  let my-own-age-experience age-experience
  ask other turtles
  [ set more-dominant ifelse-value (age-experience > my-own-age-experience)
      [ true ]
      [ false ]
  ]
  set dominant-flockmates other turtles with [ more-dominant ]
end
```

But if the only reason to have the variable is to create the agentset, you can do the whole thing directly:

```
to find-dominant-flockmates
  let my-own-age-experience age-experience
  set dominant-flockmates other turtles with [ age-experience > my-own-age-experience ]
end
```

Comment: I am using your third version right now and it works perfectly, thanks for the quick answer!